# Convert from raw pointers to smart pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, smart-pointers

I want to use smart pointers instead of raw pointers.
How can I convert this function accordingly?

```
Node * List::next(const Node * n) const {
    return n->next;
}
```

Comment: What is it you're trying to achieve by using smart pointers?

Comment: You shouldn't be exposing that low a level of your data structure. Naked pointers are OK if they're only used privately.

Comment: Smart pointers are used for managing resources that you've allocated. The code fragment you've given works with existing raw pointers rather than allocating them so you're really not looking in the right place. Do you understand what you're trying to do with smart pointers?

Comment: I'm learning C++. I just have a code snipped where I played around with pointers, now I just want to replace them with smart pointers.

Comment: In this particular case, it would be better to use references rather than pointers.

Comment: Seriously, you're going about this the wrong way. The fact that you are using a null pointer to signal the end of the list (and thus why you want to return a pointer) is an *implementation detail*, as are the list nodes. The real interface should expose references to the list *elements*, not pointers to the nodes. And you need a different mechanism for checking for the end of the list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like this:

```
Node * List::next(const Node * n) const {
    return n->next;
}
```

As far as I can tell the function `next` doesn't not perform any transfer of ownership so it doesn't need to concern itself with means of ownership of `Node` objects so it doesn't need to change. (It doesn't need to be a member of `List` or it could be a `static` member.)